# Error are come \build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

My Gradle code is here. The app.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1 error come again and again. please tell me what is the reason behind this. ???

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ssdeveloper.nwetsun.iub"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Change `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'` to `...23.4.0'` like the rest. Plus post the entire log.

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved after clean the project.